# How to get the width a view occupies on one half of the screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get the width a view occupies on one half of the screen, but I am struggling to think of a way to do this

I tried using geometry reader

```
HStack{
  Spacer()

  Text(displayedText)
       .background(
           GeometryReader { geometry in
                  Color.clear
                  .preference(key: TextWidthKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
           }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(TextWidthKey.self) { width in
             textWidthOnRight = width / 2
        }
  Spacer()

}

struct TextWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

but the issue is that the text isn't equally divided on both side of the screen, therefore the calculation is inaccurate

Comment: Look into `SwiftUI.Layout`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, why the code in your question should not deliver the correct result if the text is in an `HStack` between two `Spacer`. I would expect it to be exactly centered, so half the text width will be on the right-hand side.

However, it would be a different matter if one of the two `Spacer` would not be there, because then the text will be pushed to either the left or the right side. To find the right-hand width in this case, you need the full view width for reference and also the position of the text frame in the global coordinate space.

Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outer in
        HStack{

//            Spacer()
            Text(displayedText)
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        let fullWidth = outer.size.width
                        let textWidth = geometry.size.width
                        let textFrame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(
                                key: TextWidthKey.self,
                                value: textFrame.minX < fullWidth / 2
                                    ? max(0, textWidth + textFrame.minX - (fullWidth / 2))
                                    : textWidth
                            )
                    }
               )
                .onPreferenceChange(TextWidthKey.self) { width in
//                    print("textWidthOnRight = \(width)")
                    textWidthOnRight = width
                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

You will notice that two special cases are being handled:

- If the text does not reach to the center of the view frame, perhaps because it is short and pushed to the left side, a width of 0 is delivered (instead of a negative value).
- On the other hand, if the text is pushed to the right and starts after the center of the screen then the full text width is delivered. The leading blank space between the view center and the start of text is ignored.

Comment: I think because not all ascii characters are the same length, but I'm not sure, I am getting wrong results